# How to verify an observable object have all the required members?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, validation, jsonschema

Basically I want to validate my observable before apply the bindings, so that I will never get that something something is not defined error.

Say I do have a javascript class that defines all that I need, and I want to validate an observable created from ajax against it.

Is there a generic way to do it?

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rgneko/GuR8v/

Currently the demo will throw error because one of the items has no id property. I want to verify whether all items are valid.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ModelToTestAgainst(id, name, type, items) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.items = items;
    }
    var data = {
        items: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'name1',
            type: 'folder',
            items: []
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'name2',
            type: 'file',
            items: []
        }, {
            name: 'name2',
            type: 'file',
            items: []
        }]
    };
    var someRandomObservaleIGotFromWherever = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    // I want to Validate(someRandomObservaleIGotFromWherever) before apply bindings

    ko.applyBindings(someRandomObservaleIGotFromWherever);
});
```

Comment: You should make your question a little clearer showing some sample code, and explaining what you'd like to check generically. We cannot imagine what you've got in your head...

Comment: @JotaBe I've added fiddle. Hope it explains better.

Comment: JSON Schema are gaining traction.  Maybe you could trying validating the data via a known schema.  (https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) is a library under active development you could try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard JSON Schema, defined in http://json-schema.org/.

An schema can be as simple as:

```
var schema = {"type" : "object"};
```

which requires the value to be an object. Or much more complex, like this example from json-schema.org:

```
{
  "title": "Example Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  },
  "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

which requires several properties to exists, defines their types, and even a minimun value for one of them.

Then you need a library that allows to validate the JS objects with this kind of schema. In the same site, you can find [a list of libraries for validating (and parsing, creating documentation...)](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html). Note that not all libraries are updated, and not all of them support the latest JSON schema version.

For example, [using JSV](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV), you can make a validation simply like this:

```
var report = env.validate(json, schema);
```

Comment: Thanks! I remember reading about this some time ago. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you map/wrap it into a view model that you know has all the properties that you need?

```
function ViewModel(model) {
    this.x = ko.observable(model.x || 0);
    this.y = ko.observable(model.y || 0);
}
var original = { x: 27 }; // Use your ajax object here.
var viewModel = new ViewModel(original);
```

Comment: In some cases I just get my observable from wherever and cannot modify it, because it is shared with other parts of the code. I guess the best I can do would be creating a wrapper over the observable, but I think it's kind of cumbersome, and in my case it's kind of an over kill.

Answer (score 0):

What about using JSON Schema validation.

I have used library from [Tiny Validator](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) to enable validation.  Validation is easy to add as an observable extension

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Attach a validationSchema method to all observable types
    ko.subscribable.fn["validateSchema"] = function(schema){
        // Convert the observable back to an object literal to test.
        var source = ko.mapping.toJS(this());

        return tv4.validate(source, schema);
    };

    // Define schema for ModelToTestAgainst
    var modelSchema = {
        "$schema": "http://tempuri.org/ModelToTestAgainst",
        "title": "ModelToTestAgainst Set",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "title": "ModelToTestAgainst",
            "type": "object",
            "properties" : {
                "id" : { 
                    "type": "number", 
                    "minimum" : 1
                },
                "name" : { "type": "string" },
                "type" : { "type": "string" },
                "items" : { "type" : "array" }
            },
            "required": ["id", "name", "type", "items"]
        }
    };
    function ModelToTestAgainst(id, name, type, items) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.items = items;
    }
    var data = {
        items: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'name1',
            type: 'folder',
            items: []
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'name2',
            type: 'file',
            items: []
        }, {
            name: 'name2',
            type: 'file',
            items: []
        }]
    };
    var obs = ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    var isValid = obs.items.validateSchema(modelSchema);

    if( isValid ) {        
        ko.applyBindings(obs);
    }
});
```